# Why does computer data get destroyed when it gets downloaded?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, computers

Whenever an enemy ship downloads something from the board computer or whenever a hologram gets transferred, the data gets removed from the board computer. It's almost as if the data was a physical object. Why doesn't the original data get preserved like with current computers? It seems so illogical to do it that way.

Some examples:

Voyager 6x24 - The doctor gets transferred to the alpha quadrant in order to treat Louis Zimmerman. The Voyager doesn't have the EMH for that time period

Voyager 7x05 - The Doctor's mobile emitter gets stolen and replaced with a replicated copy. The original Doctor isn't in the board computer anymore

Voyager 7x06 - Barclays hologram gets intercepted on the way to the Delta quadrant and you can hear on multiple occasions in the episode that the hologram is gone.

Comment: Could you give some examples of specific episodes where this occurred?

Comment: @Kitkat Some examples: Voyager 6x24 - The doctor gets transferred to the alpha quadrant in order to treat Louis Zimmerman. The Voyager doesn't have the EMH for that time period; Voyager 7x05 - The Doctor's mobile emitter gets stolen and replaced with a replicated copy. The original Doctor isn't in the board computer anymore; Voyager 7x06 - Barclays hologram gets intercepted on the way to the Delta quadrant and you can hear on multiple occasions in the episode that the hologram is gone.

Comment: You're talking mostly about data that represents actual *people*. That could well be a special case.

Comment: Most likely, this is just hand-waving by the writers. In more serious terms, though, the question of what to do with the original after download is vexing. If you don't destroy the original, you wind up with two identical individuals. Which is the "real" one? After multiple downloads, which of multiple instances owns property, or is married to a non-replicated spouse? A destroy-after-download policy might be used. See, for instance, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_Like_a_Dinosaur